# How to have multiple toggle at the same time for 2 different div?

Tags: toggle, jquery

I need to handle multiple slide toggle for 2 different divs using jquery.

example: when I click a button, it should slideLeft the 1st div and at the same time it should expand the 2nd div covering the whole area of the 1st div.

Thanks in advance.

Here the piece of code I have used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').click(function() {
        $('#accordian').toggle("slide", 300);
        if ($(this).val() == "Hide Menu"){
            $(this).val("Show Menu");
            $('#area').css({"max-width":"960px"});
        }else{
            $(this).val("<< Hide Menu");
            $('#area').css({"max-width":"730px"});
        }
    });
```

Comment: Put the code for both in the same click handler, it's that simple

Comment: Hello Asad, can you please elobrate with some example?